# Powerpoint Random Name Selection VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following VBA code in Powerpoint 2010 to pick a name from a list at random:

```
Dim hat As New Collection

Sub fill_the_hat()
Dim items() As String
Dim x As Long
items = Split("Test\Names\John\Bob\Chris\Mike\Robert\Adam", "\")
For x = 0 To UBound(items)
hat.Add(items(x))
Next x
End Sub

Sub pick_one()
Dim x As Long
Randomize
x = Int(Rnd * hat.Count) + 1
MsgBox hat(x)
hat.Remove (x)
End Sub
```

I need to adapt this to output to a text box rather than a MsgBox but this doesn't seem as obvious as I thought it would be?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Many Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to adress your UserForm and TextBox directly to change the contents. An example would be:

```
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = x
```

This has to happen before the UserForm1.Show call or alternatively you have to refresh the form via UserForm1.Repaint

Comment: Hi Haris, thanks for your answer, there is no UserForm though, it is just a TextBox directly on the slide in PowerPoint?

Comment: Upon investigation the code you supplied worked, I just needed to change UserForm1 to Slide1: "Slide1.TextBox1.Text = hat(x)", Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just displaying the name there is no need at all to use an ActivX textbox. Just use a normal shape or textbox

ActivePresenation.Slides(1).Shapes ("nameofshape").Textframe.TextRange=hat(x)

Also when you use my code from the net it is more normal to say "I got this code from John Wilson's article here" rather that "I have this code"

Comment: This is a project I inherited off a colleague? I have no idea who you are, but I would suggest if you have a problem with people using your code, you don't post it on the internet...